# Connect Dlink DIR-615 to existing wireless network

Tags: wireless-networking, openwrt, firmware

I could not find a concrete answer around the net, and thought to post it here since the **best** answer is easier to emerge.

I want to use my D-Link DIR-615 as a wireless bridge to connect a remote device with no wireless to my wireless network. How can I achieve this?

The main router (from KisMac):

Vendor: Thomson Telecom Belgium

Channel: 8

Main Channel: 6

Type: Managed

Encryption: WPA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the hardware revision of your device, for instance DD-WRT supports all except revision D1.  If you use DD-WRT then they provide some [good instructions](http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Client_Bridged).  I didn't see anything for OpenWRT but I assume they have similar documentation.

---

Did you work through [those instructions](http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Client_Bridged)?  Did you look at the thread linked in it?  I'm afraid that I've never used that feature of DD-WRT so all I can do is recommend you make use of the DD-WRT forum.

Comment: @Cry Havoc Currently I am trying DD-Wrt... will update with results

Comment: @Cry Havoc: You were right DD-wrt has very descriptive instructions and got in installed easily. Somewhere the setup does not work, but this is another story :-)

Comment: So I'm currently with DD-WRT (Firmware: DD-WRT v24-sp2 (10/12/10) std) but for some reason I can not get it at all to connect to the speedtouch router. So I am on the verge of admitting defeat here. And we also turned an OpenWRT question to a DD-Wrt one.

Comment: @dimitris, so change the title ;)

Comment: @Cry Havok: Honestly thought the question titles were cast in stone.

Comment: In any case I could not connect the router and the DLink together, so I feel constantly pushed back to square one.

Comment: @Dimitris, worth looking at the thread linked in the instructions I linked to.  There are apparently some known problems and they should be able to help you there.

Comment: @Cry Havoc: I thought that the best case was to follow this: http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Client_Mode which is a bit easier. My main problem is that the two routers don't seem to get along

Comment: @Cry Havoc: Thank you for reminding me **not** to underestimate the power of doing something 15 times until it works :-)

Comment: @Dimitris Glad you git it sorted in the end

Comment: Update: AFter 1.5 months of happiness the main router had a hiccup. After that  somehow DIR-615 took over and none in the house could use their wireless...

Comment: I sill try the procedure again and update (or just buy a bridge)

Answer (score 0):

You might try [Fonera 2.0 firmware](http://trac.fonosfera.org/fon-ng).

Comment: Hi Harry, you might have read the responses, do you think Fonera would help?

Comment: I never tried it, but some people recommended it for the D-Link DIR-615.